# Synchro Entity and Base Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I can't remember what's the command to synchronise the online database structure with the local doctrine entity.

I know that one is Entity -> Base

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I'm looking for Base -> Entity

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is not in the list of the suggested commands when you do just

`php app/console`

it doesn't exist or the bundle you used isn't properly added, I never used a command to do it in the other direction.

The documentation suggests it does exists:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: I tried it, but it tells me doctrine can't handle reverse engineering with a table which have no primary key.

Comment: Then you should add a primary key in your db table that's giving the error.

Comment: Well...those table are not mine, so I can't do that...it's just a copy on an existing table of some company.

Comment: i'm afraid you can't do much then, the primary key is a requirement (and anyway a bad design if a table doesn't have one.)

Comment: Ok thanks :( It's sad but I guess i have to add all the field one by one now^^

Comment: I'm actually not sure your entity will work if you don't define a primary key in them.

Comment: Well, as I said, it's not mine and I'm not using it so...not really my problem...I think iut's working but I'm just surprised nobody fixed that sooner...